# unmerge css and js files on magento admin back-end

Tags: magento-1.7, javascript, css, git

I've made some changes on my local. then when i git push my changes to dev environment I don't see them. When I was inspecting my code I noticed that the css on my local are different because the css files on dev are merged.

I would like to know how can i un-merge the js and css files on the dev environment so that they look the same as the ones on my local

Comment: Do you mean turning off the merge settings under `System` > `Configuration` > `Developer` > `CSS / JS`?

Comment: Added my comment as answer, was not sure if you meant this setting :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can turn off compression under `System` > `Configuration` > `Developer` > `CSS / JS` and then change the value in the dropdown.